# GROUP BY with multiple counts

Tags: mysql, group-by, count

I'm querying an Invoice table in a MySQL 8.0.28 database that is a child to the Customer table (FK = CustomerId) and I want to be able to get multiple counts based on different criteria over the last 30 days where I group by the customer and the invoice's source. So if I wrote it as 2 separate queries, it would be like this:

```
/* this is just the count of all invoices in last 30 days */
SELECT i.CustomerId, i.InvoiceSource, COUNT(*) AS TotalInvoices
FROM Invoice i
WHERE i.CreatedDate BETWEEN (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH ) and CURDATE() 
GROUP BY i.CustomerId, i.InvoiceSource;
```

and

```
/* count of all invoices in last 30 days where the total amount exceeds 1000 */
SELECT i.CustomerId, i.InvoiceSource, COUNT(*) AS LargeInvoices
FROM Invoice i
WHERE i.CreatedDate BETWEEN (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) and CURDATE() AND i.Amount > 1000
GROUP BY i.CustomerId, i.InvoiceSource;
```

You get the idea, there will probably be 2 or 3 more with specific criteria as well.

So my questions are:

1. first and foremost what is the best approach and SQL to write this as a single query?
2. will it start to bog down the query as I add more counts for different conditions? if so, what's the over/under on that?
3. The GROUP BY is the same for all, am I able to move that out of each subquery and make it as a group by for the entire thing? Not sure if that would be more efficient or not?

much obliged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to use a CASE inside an aggregation function.

As an example, you could combine the two queries this way:

```
SELECT
    i.CustomerId,
    i.InvoiceSource,
    COUNT(*) AS TotalInvoices,
    SUM(CASE WHEN i.Amount >1000 then 1 ELSE 0 END ) as LargeInvoices
FROM
    Invoice i
WHERE
    i.CreatedDate BETWEEN (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
    and CURDATE()
GROUP BY
    i.CustomerId,
    i.InvoiceSource;
```

It could also be done with COUNT:

```
SELECT
    i.CustomerId,
    i.InvoiceSource,
    COUNT(*) AS TotalInvoices,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN i.Amount >1000 then 1 ELSE NULL END ) as LargeInvoices
FROM
    Invoice i
WHERE
    i.CreatedDate BETWEEN (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
    and CURDATE()
GROUP BY
    i.CustomerId,
    i.InvoiceSource;
```

Comment: Great, thanks, very simple and clean solution @Eric Prevost

Comment: Or...  `SUM(i.Amount >1000)`